# How do I create a less mixin that outputs centralized css rules?

Tags: css, less

I am trying to minimize my code output when using [`lessjs`](http://lesscss.org/).

Currently I have code that sets media queries for different elements using the `@rules()` method and looks like this:

```
.screen-xs ( @rules ){
    @media only screen and (min-width: @screen-xs){
        @rules();
    }
}

.logo {
    width: 100px;

    .screen-xs({ width: 50px; });
}
```

This works fine but when I use it more than a couple of time I get a massive output of `@media` lines.

What I want to know is if there is a way to minimize the above with some overlooked less feature I could not find?

i.e. Maybe something that will take all the `@rules` I throw into `.screen-xs` and just place them into one `@media` declaration?

Comment: LESS doesn't have @media merging (yet).  I've used mixins to do it, but it's kind of hack-y.  Basically, since mixing in a LESS mixin will call every instance of that mixin, you can define as many `.screen-xs () {}`es as you want.  If your interested in a demo, I can share.

Comment: @calvin Sure, a demo would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Haha, it seems @seven-phases-max beat me to the punch.  His demo is perfect.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments above it is possible to force consolidation of `@media` wrapped styles via mixins, e.g. (just one of possible variants, but all of those will be more verbose and less readable compared to your current code):

```css
.logo {
    width: 100px;
}

.screen-xs() {
    .logo {width: 50px;}
}

.intro {
    width: 200px;
}

.screen-xs() {
    .intro {width: 100px;}
}

#footer > div {
    width: 25%;
}

.screen-md() {
    #footer > div {width: 10%;}
}

// ........................................

@media only screen and (min-width: 222px) {
    .screen-xs();
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 555px) {
    .screen-md();
}

// etc.
```

As for automatic merging, see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/950.

P.S. Also see [LESS CSS retina media queries without redundancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000660) for another (more extended) approaches.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have one issue with the above method in that it does not allow for nesting. If the `.screen-md()` mixin is nested i.e. `#footer { .screen-md(){ > div {width: 10%;} } }` then the parser does not recognize the mixin and throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

### Straight answer: Currently, there is no option to do this through less.

### Alternative Solution

Use a [postprocessor](http://gulpjs.com/) to combine all `@media` rules.

You can use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [gulp-cmq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-combine-mq/) to group all `@media` rules:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    cmq = require('gulp-combine-media-queries');

// CSS concat, auto-prefix and minify
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src(['./less/make.less'])
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(cmq())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
});

// default gulp task
gulp.task('default', ['styles']);
```

### INPUT (before combine)

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
  .logo { width: 100px; }

/* Several lines down ... */

@media (min-width: 768px)
  .header { color: blue; }
```

### Output (after combine)

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
  .logo { width: 100px; }
  .header { color: blue; }
```

You can also use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for the above with [grunt-cmq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-combine-media-queries).