# Prevent LESS mixins with duplicate pseudo classes from creating additional CSS definitions

Tags: css, less, prepros

I have created a number of mixins to speed up setting anchor properties for each state.  In this example I have a mixin for `text-decoration` and another for `background-color`.

```
.link-text-decoration(@default, @hover, @active, @visited)
{
    text-decoration: @default;
    &:hover
    {
        text-decoration: @hover;
    }
    &:active
    {
        text-decoration: @active;
    }
    &:visited
    {
        text-decoration: @visited;
    }
}

.link-background-color(@default, @hover, @active, @visited)
{
    background-color: @default;
    &:hover
    {
        background-color: @hover;
    }
    &:active
    {
        background-color: @active;
    }
    &:visited
    {
        background-color: @visited;
    }
}
```

When rendering as CSS I find instead of merging the pseudo classes it redeclares another.

**LESS CSS calling the Mixins**

```
.link
{
    .link-text-decoration(underline, none, none, underline);
    .link-background-color(#fff, #ccc, #ddd, #fff);
}
```

**The Result**

There a 2 instances of `hover`, `active` and `visited`.

```
.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.link:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.link:active {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.link:visited {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

**Desired Result**

Ideally I would like the values to appear as below as this would be much more efficient.

```
.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.link:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.link:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I've played with the [Extend function](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) and the examples on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/), but this does not seem to work for this scenario.

Any solution, guidance, or advice?
Thanks,

Comment: There's method (similar to what used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000660/less-css-retina-media-queries-without-redundancy/26007476#26007476), but it will need one extra line on use). However I'd suggest for your production CSS build just use `--clean-css="advanced"` option (or `clean-css` as a standalone build step) - it will merge those duplicates automatically.