# LESS - combine rules of media queries with same condition

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I am using the following LESS mixin to optimize background images for 2x screens.

**Definition::**

```
.image-2x(@image, @width: auto, @height: auto, @repeat: no-repeat) {
  @filename  : ~`/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/.exec(@{image})[1]`;
  @extension : ~`/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/.exec(@{image})[2]`;
  background-image: ~`"url(@{filename}.@{extension})"`;
  background-repeat: @repeat;
  background-size: @width @height;
  @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {
      background-image: ~`"url(@{filename}@2x.@{extension})"`;
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage::**

```
selector1 {
  .image-2x("path/to/image1.png"); 
}
selector2 {
  .image-2x("path/to/image2.png"); 
}
```

**Output::**

```
selector1 {
  background-image: url(path/to/image1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
}
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    selector1 {
      background-image: url(path/to/image1@2x.png);
    }
  }
}
selector2 {
  background-image: url(path/to/image2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
}
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    selector2 {
      background-image: url(path/to/image2@2x.png);
    }
  }
}
```

**Optimal Output::**

```
selector1 {
  background-image: url(path/to/image1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
}
selector2 {
  background-image: url(path/to/image2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
}
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    selector1 {
      background-image: url(path/to/image1@2x.png);
    }
    selector2 {
      background-image: url(path/to/image2@2x.png);
    }
  }
}
```

To achieve this I thought of storing the @2x background image urls in a list and then printing all the saved rulesets at the end of file within one media query. but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Can anyone suggest a solution, I am fine with any kind of approach.

I am using `grunt-contrib-less` to compile my less. if any compiler optimizes the output, please mention it.

Comment: See [group-css-media-queries](https://github.com/SE7ENSKY/group-css-media-queries) and similar instruments. And (just for facultative reference, since it's not necessary because of mentioned tools) a pure Less approaches in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000660.

Comment: group-css-media-queries seems lika a good post processing tool. i would take it as a last resort if less solution is not available